# When an ADF pipeline is executing can we deploy a new version to the same ADF?

Tags: azure-data-factory

And if we deploy then what would happen to the currently running pipeline?
eg: I start running a pipeline in Production Env. It will take 5 hours to complete. I deploy another version of ADF to production(added another pipeline). What would happen to the currently running pipeline in prd?

Triggers will be switched off and on during deployment that is not part of the question or a concern.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course you can.

There are 'pipelines' and 'pipeline instances' in ADF. When you deploy, the actual running pipeline instance is not affected. No matter what you change, the already running pipeline will continue to run according to the settings it started.

One pipeline can derive multiple pipeline instances, you only change the configuration settings of pipeline or trigger, so deploy will not change the pipeline instance which is already running.